# mysql if without select

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I'm using mysql and I want to use the `if` statement in a way you are doing in a stored procedure. Something like this:

```
delimiter $$

  if @myVariable is null then
    drop temporary table tmp_buffer;
    select 'cannot proceed without variable @myVariable';
  else
    update my_table as t
    set t.name = @myVariable;
  end;

end$$

delimiter ;
```

When I execute this code it does nothing. 
I tried to google this but I only find `select if(....)` explanations what doesn’t fit to my requirements.
I know that it is possible to create a stored procedure and put the code there and then call the procedure, but I'm looking for a way to do it without stored procedures.
Is this possible? If yes, what is wrong in my code?

Thanks for reading this

Felix

Comment: AFAIK, no; you have to put this in a stored procedure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I'm looking for a way to do it without stored procedures. Is this
>   possible?

NO; as already commented above, you cann't use `if .. else` construct block like the way you are intend to use in a normal SQL query. You will have to wrap it inside a procedural block which could be a stored procedure or a function.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your answer. I will wrap a stored procedure around it ;)